# How to make a word with lines in codes?

Tags: html, c++, unix, comments, symbols

I have seen many websites, programs and applications include custom branding with lines and dashes. Is there a generator for that? I want to print some alphaberts in C++ but I couldn't find any generator for it and I tried to type it out manually but I couldn't make it look nice.

If you go to certbot and take a look at their codes, here is what you will most likely find:

```
<!--

 ██████╗███████╗██████╗ ████████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗
██╔════╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝
██║     █████╗  ██████╔╝   ██║   ██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║
██║     ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗   ██║   ██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║
╚██████╗███████╗██║  ██║   ██║   ██████╔╝╚██████╔╝   ██║
 ╚═════╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝   ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝    ╚═╝

Like looking at code? Help us! https://github.com/certbot/certbot
                               https://github.com/certbot/website

-->
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows a way to generate these words using symbols? Nothing on Google have shown anything about this, they either come out with English essay generator or the actual electric generator. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the generator called the ASCII art generator. Below is a link to one of the ASCII generator if anyone needs. It actually makes sense since ASCII is the name for the characters. The ANSI shadow font is the exact match for Certbot's font.

http://patorjk.com/software/taag

I know this is a dumb question but I'm sure there are people looking for it... Hope this helps somebody.